# Maintaining WebAPI endpoints in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I was wondering if there were any good techniques in keeping your WebAPI controller routes in sync with the client side.

For instance, you have a WebAPI controller BooksController.  On the client you could invoke a method by calling the endpoint:

```
$.get('books/1');
```

Then one day you decide to rename the controller, or add a RoutePrefix. This breaks the client side code, as the endpoint has changed.

I came across the library [WebApiProxy](https://github.com/faniereynders/WebApiProxy), which looks interesting. Does anyone have a good approach to solving this problem? Is there a reason to use string literals on the client that I may be overlooking?

Comment: What libraries are you using on the client side?

Comment: Vanilla JS. Is there a library that makes this cleaner?

Comment: Hm, I think that using some magic library which generate some js proxies according to the Web API implementation is not very good, form my point of view, is better to have control over what is going on. In other words, my suggestion is to have route configuration on the client side too, for example using requirejs, you can call **require.toUrl('books/1')**, and according the the require js configuration this url can replaced with the actual one, for example 'http://localhost/mywebaby/books/1'. If the Web API changes you can change the client side configuration.

Comment: I've never seen the require.toUrl syntax, do you have a link to a reference?

Comment: Here is the documentation http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#modulenotes-urls, http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-map, but you can use any other library, or just do it by yourself - use some function which will tell you the real address, input param into this function will be the route you use in your javascript, and inside this method (using regex for instance) create the real url

Comment: Have you looked at my answer?

Answer (score 1):

I created a blog bost on te subject. Take a look :)

http://blog.walden.dk/post/2017/02/02/export-all-your-asp-net-webapi-endpoints-to-json

Im working on a post consuming it in javascript.. Anyway, this code exports the endpoints runtime, and will work on refactorings and route changes. It exports  uri parameters as well, they can be used to be parsed in javascript and replaced with values from the client.

The simplest way to achieve waht you want, is to use the built-in ApiExplorer in ASP.NET WEBAPI. It searches for all "ApiController" implementations, and reads the route-attribute metadata.

```
public class EndpointManager
{
    public IEnumerable<ApiMethodModel> Export()
    {
        //Use the build-in apiexplorer to find webapi endpoints
        IApiExplorer apiExplorer = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.GetApiExplorer();
        //exclude endpoints without the attribute
        var apiMethods = apiExplorer.ApiDescriptions.Select(ad => new ApiMethodModel(ad)).ToList();
        return apiMethods;
    }
}
```

You can create an endpoint that returns that generated data.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/endpoint")]
public class EndpointApiController : ApiController {
 [HttpGet]
    [Route("all")]
    public IEnumerable<ApiMethodModel> All()
    {
        var endpoints = new EndpointManager().Export();
        return endpoints;
    }
}
```

Now all the endpoints can be reached at "/api/endpoint/all"

Answer (score 0):

Here is an sample I was talking about in my comment to your question:

```js
function getUrl(uri) {
  var bookRoute = /books(.*?)/i;
  var otherRoute = /something(.*?)/i;
  
  if(uri.match(bookRoute)) {
    return uri.replace(bookRoute, "http://localhost/webapi/books$1")
  }
  
  if(uri.match(otherRoute)) {
    return uri.replace(otherRoute, "http://mydomain/api/something$1")
  }
  
  return uri;
}

alert(getUrl("books/1"));
alert(getUrl("something/realy/different/1"));
```

All you need is to define the routes in the body of your function.

Comment: I guess you still need to hard code the available routes in JavaScript.  I'm looking to avoid putting string literals into JavaScript and have some other mechanism create the endpoints.

Comment: You could stop looking at it as hardcoded string literals, and start looking at it as configuration for your client side application. You will have better control over how it is all working, rather than using some magic library which will in the end do the same, read your server api routes and generate some javascript proxies. That's my point of view.

Comment: I get your point.  It doesnt solve the issue if you change the name of a controller you force yourself to do a Find In All Files operation looking for all the instances using that route config.  I get you can put it all in one location, but why not go a step further and have the server generates it.  I mean it knows the routes via the route table, I dont see why it couldn't emit that to the client.

Comment: Find in All files is really not necessary, I suggest to have it at one place, and that place would be the only one to change. And as you are saying, it seems that you expect that your routes will change frequently, if it so, than you should rethink it all, because, why the routes should even change? How often they will change? The magic javascript proxies generation has been there since ASP.NET ScriptManager and where did it go?